# convert pandas dataframe column of dtype object to date type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, type-conversion

I have a dataframe df and has a column by name timeframe of dtype object

| column_a | timeframe |
| --- | --- |
| One | nov-21 |
| Two | jun-90 |

I would like to convert timeframe column to date type but this conversion fails with **error Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-11-21 00:00:00**

```
df['timeframe'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the format:

```
df['timeframe'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeframe'], format="%b-%y", errors="coerce")
```

Comment: I get ValueError: unconverted data remains: -1900

Comment: You have values in your dataframe that do not match the "nov-21" format. See the edit. Include the "errors=coerce" to force the invalid values to `NaN`